# Entity Framework update only specific columns - EntityState.Modified error and Attach gives error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I was looking on stackoverflow and see selected answers which led me to believe that this was fine to do but I get this error

```
//db.Entry(tips).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.tblTips.Attach(tips);
db.Entry(tips).Property(x => x.createdby).IsModified = false;
db.Entry(tips).Property(x => x.created).IsModified = false;
tips.updated = DateTime.Now;
var recordsUpdated = db.SaveChanges();
```

Error below from either of this lines

```
db.Entry(tips).State = EntityState.Modified;
or..
db.tblTips.Attach(tips);
```

> Attaching an entity of type 'BRM.Data.Models.tblTips' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

Should I do this:

```
if (TryUpdateModel(newsToUpdate, "",
           new string[] { "LastName", "FirstMidName", "EnrollmentDate" }))
```

I will have int and datetime as well

**UPDATE**

```
1. Should I use `db.Entry(newsToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;` 
2. OR use `db.Entry(newsToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;`
```

Below I am seeing that if use model from parameter of the method to update specific fields, but then use `.Entry` for the `newToUpdate` which is the model hydrated from the database  -  does this seem "ok?"

```
db.Entry(newsToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
//db.tblTips.Attach(newsToUpdate);
db.Entry(newsToUpdate).Property(x => x.createdby).IsModified = false;
db.Entry(newsToUpdate).Property(x => x.created).IsModified = false;
newsToUpdate.updated = DateTime.Now;
newsToUpdate.body = tips.body;
newsToUpdate.title = tips.title;
var recordsUpdated = db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: First question is: what's the lifespan of `db`?

Comment: I never thought of that , in my controller I have it defined at the top in the class as     private DOCContext db = new DOCContext();

Comment: Then it effectively lasts as long as the action method runs. So the next question is, what happens before `db.tblTips.Attach(tips);`?

Comment: This is all trial and error.  Instead, please provide the exception type (ex. `NullReferenceException`), the exception message and the StackTrace.

Comment: See my answer, I guess I could edit my question, but I am going to post an answer and I know I'm getting "closer"    thx guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,  this works

Code:

```
db.Entry(newsToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
//db.tblTips.Attach(newsToUpdate);
db.Entry(newsToUpdate).Property(x => x.createdby).IsModified = false;
db.Entry(newsToUpdate).Property(x => x.created).IsModified = false;
newsToUpdate.updated = DateTime.Now;
newsToUpdate.body = tips.body;
newsToUpdate.title = tips.title;
var recordsUpdated = db.SaveChanges();
```